# Is Mapreduce job using multiplethreading

Tags: multithreading, hadoop, mapreduce

I am curious about whether mapreduce job is using multiple threading in a single machine. For example, I have 10 servers in the hadoop cluster, by default, if the input file is large enough, there will be 10 mappers. Is the single mapper using multiple threading in a single machine?

Comment: Each mapper would run in its own JVM.

Comment: @ Binary Nerd Not exactly. mapper doesn't own a JVM. it depends on how many hadoop instances are deployed in one server. What I want to say is one hadoop instance own a jvm not mapper

Comment: every task run in its own JVM, so that means that one mapper is one JVM process.

Comment: We can discuss the jvm question in another thread.  it is off topic. Is the mapper multiple threading in its own jvm?

Comment: @Robinson : I mentioned the case which I have used.pls check.

Comment: @Robinson: my answer helped you ? Have you tried with the example given below ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is the single mapper using multiple threading in a single machine?

**YES.   Mapreduce job can use multithreaded mapper(*Multiple threads or thread pool running `map` method*) .**

- I have used for better CPU utilization for ***Map only Hbase jobs***...

  `MultiThreadedMapper` is a good fit if your operation is highly CPU intensive, could increase the speed.

mapper class should  extend `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.MultithreadedMapper` instead of regular `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper` .

> The `Multithreadedmapper` has a different implementation of run()
>   method. like below.
>
> ```
> run(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context context)
> ```
>
> **Run the application's maps using a thread pool.**

You can set the number of threads within a mapper in `MultiThreadedMapper` by

`MultithreadedMapper.setNumberOfThreads(n);`   or you can set the property in  loading from a property file `mapred.map.multithreadedrunner.threads = n`
and use above setter method(per job basis) to control jobs which are less cpu intensive.

The affect of doing this, you can see in mapreduce counters specially CPU related counters.

[Example Code snippet of MultithreadedMapper implementation](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rystsov/learning-hadoop/c9cbd249e37e29cf6345de336dda2295a869193a/src/main/java/com/twitter/rystsov/mr/MultithreadedWordCount.java):

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.MultithreadedMapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class MultithreadedWordCount {

    // class should be thread safe
    public static class WordCountMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable> {
        public static enum PREPOST { SETUP, CLEANUP }

        @Override()
        protected void setup(Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable>.Context context) throws java.io.IOException, java.lang.InterruptedException {
            // will be called several times
            context.getCounter(PREPOST.SETUP).increment(1);
        }

        @Override
        protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
                     Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            String[] words = value.toString().toLowerCase().split("[\\p{Blank}[\\p{Punct}]]+");
            for (String word : words) {
                context.write(new Text(word), new LongWritable(1));
            }
        }

        @Override()
        protected void cleanup(Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable>.Context context) throws java.io.IOException, InterruptedException {
            // will be called several times
            context.getCounter(PREPOST.CLEANUP).increment(1);
        }
    }

    public static class WordCountReducer extends Reducer<Text, LongWritable, Text, LongWritable> {
        @Override
        protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<LongWritable> values, Context context
                        ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            long sum = 0;
            for (LongWritable value: values) {
              sum += value.get();
            }
            context.write(key, new LongWritable(sum));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
        Job job = new Job();
        job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        MultithreadedMapper.setMapperClass(job, MultithreadedWordCount.WordCountMapper.class);
        MultithreadedMapper.setNumberOfThreads(job, 10);

        job.setMapperClass(MultithreadedMapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(MultithreadedWordCount.WordCountReducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(MultithreadedWordCount.WordCountReducer.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);

        /* begin defaults */
        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
        /* end defaults */

        job.waitForCompletion(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: It can, I agree with you. As the default, I think that the mapper is a single thread process.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.html

> Applications may override the run(Context) method to exert greater control on map processing e.g. multi-threaded Mappers etc.

Moreover there is also a [MultithreadedMapper](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/map/MultithreadedMapper.html) . I have never used this though.